# SWIG - c# - обертка для enum

Tags: c#, c++, enum, swig

Не могу сделать C# обертку для enum C++ c помощью SWIG. Значение членов c++ `enum`, которые я хочу обернуть превосходят максимальное значение для `Int32`. В C# тип членов enum  по умолчанию -   `Int32`, поэтому в `public enum BigNumbers { big = 0x80000000,...}` я получаю ошибку компиляции `cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'`. Несмотря на то, что я как мне кажется следую, [инструкции](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/CSharp.html#CSharp_enum_underlying_type), 
 в которой описывается данная ситуация, я не могу решить проблему. Видимо, я не понимаю чего-то базового.
Привожу код:

Заголовочный файл с enum, который нужно обернуть.

**MyClass.h**

```
class  MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {}
    ~MyClass() {}
    enum  BigNumbers
    {
        big = 0x80000000, bigger
    };
};
```

Интерфейсный файл SWIG:

**MyClass.i**

```
%module cpp

%{
    #include "MyClass.h"
%}
%include "MyClass.h"

%typemap(csbase) BigNumbers "uint"
%inline %{
  enum BigNumbers { big=0x80000000, bigger };
%}
```

В результате я имею следующую конструкцию в автоматически созданном файле  `MyClass.cs`, которая вызывает ошибку компиляции.

**MyClass.cs**

```
  public enum BigNumbers {
    big = 0x80000000,
    bigger
  }
```

и глобальный "правильный "enum c членами `uint` в отдельном файле:

**BigNumbers.cs**

```
public enum BigNumbers : uint {
  big = 0x80000000,
  bigger
}
```

хотя я ожидал увидеть его в качестве члена MyClass.

Специалисты по SWIG, отзовитесь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильное содержание интерфейсного файла следующее:

**MyClass.i**

```
%module cpp

%{
    #include "MyClass.h"

%}
%typemap(csbase) somens::MyClass::BigNumbers "uint"
%include "MyClass.h"
```